# Windows 8 Runtime (metro) Serial communication using Tera term?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, serial-port, windows-store-apps, bluetooth-lowenergy

For my senior design project, we have developed a Windows Store App to control a 2-player tug-of-war style game (all in software) which is controlled by the energy levels of each players EEG signals (specifically alpha/beta bands, relating to concentration levels) which we are transmitting over Bluetooth LE. We are also thinking about controlling a physical component to the game with an STM32F0 Microcontroller.

Basically, every so often (on some event trigger) we want to send a value between -100 and 100 in 2's complement to the uC to control the direction that the motor will move and it's speed. All the research I have done has suggested that Windows Store Apps do not support serial communication at all, but I was hoping there was a not-too-difficult workaround. We have a USB to serial adapter which will be able to communicate with the uC's UART. **Is it possible to use something like Tera Term, where the Store app could communicate with the terminal upon some event and send the data over the serial port?** Could the Windows App open tera term and write values to it? The communication need only be in one direction.

I'm open to suggestions on alternatives (aside from writing some custom driver, which would be too complicated for the amount of time that we have remaining to finish the project). Should we just completely abandon the prospect of serial communication and look into something like zigbee or bluetooth? I know it's possible to communicate over serial port using System.IO.Ports in a WPF/Windows Forms application but that is not an option at this point, since we have already developed the entirety of the host application (minus this serial comm). Thanks!!

EDIT 1: I'm considering using a UDP socket as a means of sending the necessary data to a background Windows Forms App which should be able to communicate over a serial port.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that network access to localhost is allowed with store deployed windows store apps. However Bluetooth serial port profile may be a possibility, judging by a quick google revealing [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Bluetooth-communication-7130c260).

However, given that WPF has access to a rich library of IO communications support, and it is mostly a superset of WinRT, a port may be easier than you think.